# trying to install gulp : Error: Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gulp, nvm

Newby here!

I am trying to install a react template. The template is running on node v. 14.15.4.

> nvm ls

```
> ->     v14.15.4
>        v16.15.1
>         v18.4.0
>          system default -> node (-> v18.4.0) iojs -> N/A (default) unstable -> N/A (default) node -> stable (-> v18.4.0) (default) stable
> -> 18.4 (-> v18.4.0) (default) lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> v16.15.1) lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A) lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A) lts/carbon
> -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A) lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A) lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A) lts/fermium -> v14.19.3 (-> N/A) lts/gallium ->
> v16.15.1
```

> npm install gulp-cli -g

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - /Users/theguru/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/noop.js
```

I've tried switching the node version to 18, with no luck

> ```
> npm config list
> ```

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.10 node/v14.15.4 darwin arm64"

; userconfig /Users/theguru/.npmrc
node_gyp = "/path/to/executable/node_gyp"
python = "/Applications/Python"

; node bin location = /Users/theguru/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node
; cwd = /Users/theguru/Downloads/Crypter-NFT 2
; HOME = /Users/theguru
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Any help much appreciated!